# Customizable android app store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm interested in the android app store concept. 
I'm just wondering if there is any open source project going on to develop a customizable android app store (like android market). 
It might be interesting to be able to set up your own app store.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to build a public or private app store ?

If it's private, there is a solution called Appaloosa: [Appaloosa web site](http://www.appaloosa-store.com).

It's working on android and ios, but it's not OSS.